# Executing LoadRunner scripts with different number of Users for each scenario/Function

Tags: loadrunner

I'm a newbie to the Loadrunner Tool.

I have four different scenarios which are recorded in separate functions. Now what I have to do is to run the four scenarios with different number of users.

For Eg., I have 4 scenarios like scene 1, scene2, scene 3 and scene 4. I need to run scene 1 with 10 users, scene 2 with 15 users, scene 3 with 25 users and scene 4 with 50 users.

How can I do this using LoadRunner 9.5 tool. Please help me this.

Thanks In Advance,
UdhayS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to get some terminology straight here:

**VuGen** records **ACTIONS** (not scenarios or functions) into a **script**. One script can and usually will contain multiple Actions.

In the **Controller** you create a **Scenario**. Scenarios consist of one or more Scripts. It is HERE that you define how many Vusers will be assigned to the script(s).

Example:

Recording two scripts (A and B) with 2 actions in each:

```
VuGen Script A:
   Action A1
   Action A2

VuGen Script B:
   Action B1
   Action B2
```

And then having these two scripts in a scenario:

```
Scenario X:
  Script A - 10 vusers
  Script B -  7 vusers
```

I hope this clears up some of the terminology and structure used in LoadRunner.

I also very much recommend a basic course in LoadRunner. Everything related to LoadRunner excepts one to understand and know these things.

Comment: In Vugen, we can test run a script to see the "Test Results" window.  But in the controller, how can we do so? For example, how can we obtain the random values chosen for a parameter list and also, how can we verify that `lr_rendezvous` is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

- Your business processes are recorded within indepedent scripts or functions within one script?
- You note that you are new, has your employer sent you through (HP Certified Instructor/Certfied Materials) LoadRunner Training and have you been assigned to a mentor to work with you for your first 5-6 performance testing projects?

Comment: Yes., I recorded independent functions for my scenario and called all those functions in a single function named Action(). So, when I execute the Action function from the Runtime Setting, it will invoke the function which are called in it.

Comment: You __________REALLY_________ need to attend training and have a mentor assigned to work with you. You may schedule number of users at the script level, but not at the function level.   If your management will not schedule either then you need to find more responsive management to work with